# Console.Write Not Working In Win Forms App

Tags: vb.net, winforms, console

I created a VB.NET Windows Forms Application in Visual Studio 2008.  When I run my program from the command-line, I get no output (only the next prompt).

What am I doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Debug.Write("Foo")
    Debug.Flush()
    Console.WriteLine("foo")
    Console.Beep(800, 100) 'confirm this function is called'
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

**EDIT:** Can a program have a form and a console?

**EDIT2:** Ho's answer works.  However, the output appears on the next command-line prompt.  Can a Winforms application tell the command-line to wait until it's finished instead of immediately returning?

Comment: Does it do anything when run from Visual Studio directly? Since this is responding to a loading event and isn't being called, then that would mean that Form1 likely isn't being created.

Comment: Yes.  When I run it (from either VS or command line), I do hear the short beep.

Comment: You'll find the output back in the Visual Studio Output window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or if you already have a WinForms application you can attach a Console to it using the AttachConsole API.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

...

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;
```

...

```
AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
```

(Formatted as code)

Comment: VB's version of this works.  However, the output appears after the next command-line prompt.  I'm now trying to figure out how to prevent the command-line from immediately returning.

Comment: You can do "START yourapp.exe /WAIT" to make the commandline wait, but I don't think that'll give you exactly what you want.

Answer (score 12):

Tested similar code with a C# .NET Windows Form Application. Outputs and beeps nicely within Visual Studio but only beeps when run at the command line.

If I change the **Output Type** to **Console Application** under the **Application** tab for the Project properties, I get to use both the form and console :)

Comment: @Oren: Changing the project to a console app would, for example, disable the *Application Framework* switch. Which would mean that the OP might have to write quite a bit of code to replace the functionality that that switch gave him for free. Just to avoid one interop call. So I'd disagree with that one answer is better than another without knowing more of the OPs circumstances.

Comment: @ho1 Using the interop, my winform spawns a new console window, which disappears instantly as soon as my app terminates. This makes command line integration for my winform pretty messy, e.g. writing `myApp.exe /?` flashes a console window that disappears instantly. Since I have little to no experience with winforms and googling for `what is application framework` returns too general results, I ask of you: Why would I need this *Application Framework*?

Comment: @Nolonar: See this page [Application Page, Project Designer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/tzdks800.aspx), specifically the bit in the **Windows application framework properties** section. This will show you some of the things that are done automatically with the framework enabled.

Answer (score 9):

You can run your app from the console using `myApp.exe|MORE`
This way the console will show `Console.WriteLine()` calls coming from the app and will wait until the app exits.
Please excuse my bad english.

Answer (score 6):

The others are correct in saying that you need to run your app as a console app. To your question of whether you can have both a console and a GUI: yes. Simply add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` to your project, and for the app's `Main` method, include this code:

```
' here instantiate whatever form you want to be your main form '
Dim f As New Form1

' this will start the GUI loop, which will not progress past '
' this point until your form is closed '
System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(f)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try creating a new project using the "Console Application" template instead.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is:

```
Declare Function AttachConsole Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwProcessId As Int32) As Boolean
Declare Function FreeConsole Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Boolean
```

[code.....]

when needed the console output you just call AttachConsole(-1) but remember to do a FreeConsole() at the end of your program.

the only problem with this solution is that you will read something like this:

C:>yourapp.exe
C:>Hello World!

That's because a forms application runs as a child of the command prompt so the prompt returns immediately after you type the app name..

In a console application the command prompt returns after the program exits.

I am still trying to find a way to have the same behaviour (sync run) as in a console application.

Comment: Make a little cheating and simply add `Console.Write(String.Format("{0}>", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory.TrimEnd(IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)))` at the end. Well, it works only if the user has the default prompt (`$P$G`) but I assume this will fit in 99.99% of all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a command-line/console app rather than a Windows form application to use the console.