# How do I show a console output/window in a forms application?

Tags: c#, winforms, compilation, console-application

To get stuck in straight away, a very basic example:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class test
{ 
    static void Main()
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("test");
        MessageBox.Show("test");
    }
}
```

If I compile this with default options (using csc at command line), as expected, it will compile to a console application. Also, because I imported `System.Windows.Forms`, it will also show a message box.

Now, if I use the option `/target:winexe`, which I think is the same as choosing `Windows Application` from within project options, as expected I will only see the Message Box and no console output.

(In fact, the moment it is launched from command line, I can issue the next command before the application has even completed).

So, my question is - I know that you can have "windows"/forms output from a console application, but is there anyway to show the console from a Windows application?

Comment: what do you see as the difference between the two? Why not just compile as console and show a form.

Comment: @Doggett, simple - I am learning and want to understand why/how to do it, even if I never end up using it in a real application.... At the moment, I am thinking of an option that gives extra commands/output such as in VLC, however TBH, I do not need it - again, just learning and want to understand it!

Comment: I accomplished that using this tutorial: https://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/

Answer (score 217, accepted):

this one should work.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AllocConsole();
}

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool AllocConsole();
```

Comment: Awesome, this question seems to have been asked a lot, this is the only actual answer to the question I've been able to find, +1

Comment: Main problem : when you close it, all application closes.

Comment: I tested on Windows 8 and Windows 10:
- AttachConsole works from a cmd box
- AllocConsole works from Visual Studio. When alloc is needed, AttachConsole returns false. You should also call FreeConsole() before terminating the application in console mode.

In my program I used Matthew Strawbridge's code (see below), with the AttachConsole() line modified to:
if (!AttachConsole(-1)) AllocConsole();

Comment: Will this work in a user control ?   I am working on making a SSH control as a winforms component using Granados (for example), and it is background component only.  I would like to add a nice wrapper for it to display and use the console in a component as well.

Comment: This is not great, when run from the command line it pops open a _separate_ console window, and when running from the command line and trying to use `>` to redirect the output I get a separate console window and zero output in my file.

Comment: this method works so long as you don't click in the console. doing this freezes the main form. hitting ESC in the console resumes. see here for further discussion and solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418886/how-and-why-does-quickedit-mode-in-command-prompt-freeze-applications

Comment: How to print messages in this console? Console.Writeline() is not printing anything in the console.

Comment: @Sid133 - started working to me when Ive changed project output type to:
Console Application

Comment: It doesn't print anything in the console for me

Answer (score 208):

Perhaps this is over-simplistic...

Create a Windows Form project...

Then: Project Properties -> Application -> Output Type -> Console Application

Then can have Console and Forms running together, works for me

Comment: Seems simplest, fixed my issue as well.

Comment: This is definitely the best solution! Others are smarts but way complicated

Comment: Simple and worked fine. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: While, yes, technically this can be used to allow what the poster is asking for - it is not a great solution.  By doing this, if you then start your winforms application with the GUI - you will also get a console window opened.  In this case, you would need something more like Mike de Klerk's answer.

Comment: Just like @JustinGreywolf pointed out this solution holds good only for someone who wants the console enabled All the time. What if I pass an argument say `--console` and then only the console should be shown. In cases where a console is dependent on the user's input the accepted answer holds the best solution.

Comment: This is the only solution where I have been able to get my Winforms app to write output to the console when run from the command line, or to write to file when redirected on command line with `>`.  However, I was hoping for a solution that that would explain how to run as a "Console Application" only some of the time (i.e. to programmatically enable whatever it is that changing this mysterious Visual Studio setting does).  Does anyone know how this works under the hood?

Comment: Among all the solutions I've tried, either simple or complicated, this is the only one that can solve the problem in all places I tested. Yet it's way to achieve it is so simple -- too simple that the answer is short enough for one to neglect it. I think this is what we call "elegance". 1 ton of likes.

Comment: Great solution for other scenarios like mine where I created a service and wanted to be able to execute it in an interactive console passing a specific flag.

Comment: If you are building using .NET Core, you can achieve the same effect by editing the .csproj file and changing "<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>" to " <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>".

Comment: Works in the newer versions of Visual Studio like 2022, not so much in others

Answer (score 85):

If you are not worrying about opening a console on-command, you can go into the properties for your project and change it to Console Application

[image: screenshot of changing the project type].

This will still show your form as well as popping up a console window. You can't close the console window, but it works as an excellent temporary logger for debugging.

Just remember to turn it back off before you deploy the program.

Comment: Nice. This resolves the problem I have with my forms application, that I need to be able to output to a console window while supporting redirecting the output to a file. And I dont need to attach any console manually...

Comment: @JasonHarrison If you close the console window, the program closes. Also the window is always open while the program runs.

Comment: @gun2171: Thanks. The downsides to this approach is noted in the answer: the console window will appear if the application is launched with double click, Start menu, etc.

Comment: Any way to track that console close event?

Comment: I followed this and the console still didnt show

Comment: This does not work with .Net Core 5.  I only tested the single verion of .Net Core.  Besides not showing a console window, it even caused Visual Studio 2019 to completely freeze at one point after I saved it and tried to open a Form design tab.

Comment: @c-perkins I also had the same result as you (.NET Core 5 Windows Form app as Console Application doesn't show a console and running the exe doesn't output to the console in VS 2019), but I tried VS 2022 and its working both when debugging and running the exe in a cmd terminal.

Answer (score 21):

You can call `AttachConsole` using pinvoke to get a console window attached to a WinForms project: http://www.csharp411.com/console-output-from-winforms-application/

You may also want to consider Log4net ( http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html ) for configuring log output in different configurations.

Comment: +1 - Wow, I was hoping for a console.show or similar! a lot more complicated than I thought! I will leave open for the moment just in case there is a better / easier answer.

Comment: This worked for me, AllocConsole() did not because it spawned a new console window (did not dig further into AllocConsole, maybe I missed something there though).

Answer (score 21):

Create a Windows Forms Application, and change the output type to Console.

It will result in **both a console and the form** to open.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. Simple and not using WINAPI's.

Comment: I have tried many examples, but none of them produced results that fulfilled my expectations. This solution however is exactly what I wanted and by far the easiest solution.

Answer (score 14):

There are basically two things that can happen here.

Console output
It is possible for a winforms program to attach itself to the console window that created it (or to a different console window, or indeed to a new console window if desired). Once attached to the console window Console.WriteLine() etc works as expected. One gotcha to this approach is that the program returns control to the console window immediately, and then carries on writing to it, so the user can also type away in the console window. You can use start with the /wait parameter to handle this I think.

[Link to start Command syntax](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/start.mspx)

Redirected console output
This is when someone pipes the output from your program somewhere else, eg.

yourapp > file.txt

Attaching to a console window in this case effectively ignores the piping. To make this work you can call Console.OpenStandardOutput() to get a handle to the stream that the output should be piped to. This only works if the output is piped, so if you want to handle both of the scenarios you need to open the standard output and write to it and attach to the console window. This does mean that the output is sent to the console window and to the pipe but its the best solution I could find. Below the code I use to do this.

```
// This always writes to the parent console window and also to a redirected stdout if there is one.
// It would be better to do the relevant thing (eg write to the redirected file if there is one, otherwise
// write to the console) but it doesn't seem possible.
public class GUIConsoleWriter : IConsoleWriter
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

    private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

    StreamWriter _stdOutWriter;

    // this must be called early in the program
    public GUIConsoleWriter()
    {
        // this needs to happen before attachconsole.
        // If the output is not redirected we still get a valid stream but it doesn't appear to write anywhere
        // I guess it probably does write somewhere, but nowhere I can find out about
        var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
        _stdOutWriter = new StreamWriter(stdout);
        _stdOutWriter.AutoFlush = true;

        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    }

    public void WriteLine(string line)
    {
        _stdOutWriter.WriteLine(line);
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: I wasn't able to write to the console; attaching the parent process first did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: It would seem this answer requires you to rewrite all calls to `Console.WriteLine` to instead call the new `WriteLine` defined above.   Even though I tried that I was unable with this code to get anything redirected to a file when running the application on the command line and redirecting with `>` to a file.

Comment: @uglycoyote, make sure you are constructing the GUIConsoleWriter as early as possible in your application, otherwise it won't work for mysterious windows type reasons. I would argue that encapsulating calls to `Console.WriteLine` is just good practice, as it allows you to test, and to easily change the places that you log to (for example, you might want to start logging to a cloud based logging service like PaperTrail, or whatever)

Comment: this worked fine for me in Win10 without even `StreamWriter _stdOutWriter;`

Comment: Piping is the answer, but instead of to a file, just use MORE, like: yourapp | more ; please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/13010823/1845672

Answer (score 14):

This worked for me, to pipe the output to a file. 
Call the console with

> cmd /c "C:\path\to\your\application.exe" > myfile.txt

Add this code to your application.

```
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AttachConsole(UInt32 dwProcessId);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool GetFileInformationByHandle(
        SafeFileHandle hFile,
        out BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION lpFileInformation
        );
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern SafeFileHandle GetStdHandle(UInt32 nStdHandle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetStdHandle(UInt32 nStdHandle, SafeFileHandle hHandle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool DuplicateHandle(
        IntPtr hSourceProcessHandle,
        SafeFileHandle hSourceHandle,
        IntPtr hTargetProcessHandle,
        out SafeFileHandle lpTargetHandle,
        UInt32 dwDesiredAccess,
        Boolean bInheritHandle,
        UInt32 dwOptions
        );
    private const UInt32 ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    private const UInt32 STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE = 0xFFFFFFF5;
    private const UInt32 STD_ERROR_HANDLE = 0xFFFFFFF4;
    private const UInt32 DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS = 2;
    struct BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION
    {
        public UInt32 FileAttributes;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME CreationTime;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastAccessTime;
        public System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes.FILETIME LastWriteTime;
        public UInt32 VolumeSerialNumber;
        public UInt32 FileSizeHigh;
        public UInt32 FileSizeLow;
        public UInt32 NumberOfLinks;
        public UInt32 FileIndexHigh;
        public UInt32 FileIndexLow;
    }
    static void InitConsoleHandles()
    {
        SafeFileHandle hStdOut, hStdErr, hStdOutDup, hStdErrDup;
        BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION bhfi;
        hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        hStdErr = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
        // Get current process handle
        IntPtr hProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
        // Duplicate Stdout handle to save initial value
        DuplicateHandle(hProcess, hStdOut, hProcess, out hStdOutDup,
        0, true, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
        // Duplicate Stderr handle to save initial value
        DuplicateHandle(hProcess, hStdErr, hProcess, out hStdErrDup,
        0, true, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
        // Attach to console window – this may modify the standard handles
        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
        // Adjust the standard handles
        if (GetFileInformationByHandle(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), out bhfi))
        {
            SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hStdOutDup);
        }
        else
        {
            SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hStdOut);
        }
        if (GetFileInformationByHandle(GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE), out bhfi))
        {
            SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, hStdErrDup);
        }
        else
        {
            SetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE, hStdErr);
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // initialize console handles
        InitConsoleHandles();

        if (args.Length != 0)
        {

            if (args[0].Equals("waitfordebugger"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Attach the debugger now");
            }
            if (args[0].Equals("version"))
            {
#if DEBUG
                String typeOfBuild = "d";
#else
                String typeOfBuild = "r";
#endif
                String output = typeOfBuild + Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
                    .GetName().Version.ToString();
                //Just for the fun of it
                Console.Write(output);
                Console.Beep(4000, 100);
                Console.Beep(2000, 100);
                Console.Beep(1000, 100);
                Console.Beep(8000, 100);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

I found this code here: http://www.csharp411.com/console-output-from-winforms-application/
I thought is was worthy to post it here as well.

Comment: This works great EXCEPT it now fails in Windows 8 and Windows 10.  By fails I mean there's no output except and extra prompt (if that's a clue).Someone suggested AllocConsole but that just flashed a cmd window.

Comment: Also tried Chaz's answer above but that gives a new console in Windows 7 (lathough not in 8 or 10). I just need the option to run with redirection on the command line or run as a gui if there are no args.

Comment: I tried this but did not work.  With just `AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)` I get the console output but redirecting it on the command line with `>` does not work.  When I try this answer, I can't get any output whatsoever, either in the console or in a file.

Comment: valid for NET 6-7?

Answer (score 7):

```
//From your application set the Console to write to your RichTextkBox 
//object:
Console.SetOut(new RichTextBoxWriter(yourRichTextBox));

//To ensure that your RichTextBox object is scrolled down when its text is 
//changed add this event:
private void yourRichTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    yourRichTextBox.SelectionStart = yourRichTextBox.Text.Length;
    yourRichTextBox.ScrollToCaret();
}

public delegate void StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(string text);
public class RichTextBoxWriter : TextWriter
{
    private readonly RichTextBox _richTextBox;
    public RichTextBoxWriter(RichTextBox richTexttbox)
    {
        _richTextBox = richTexttbox;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        SetText(value.ToString());
    }

    public override void Write(string value)
    {
        SetText(value);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(char value)
    {
        SetText(value + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string value)
    {
        SetText(value + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding => Encoding.ASCII;

    //Write to your UI object in thread safe way:
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
        // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the  
        // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.  
        // If these threads are different, it returns true.  
        if (_richTextBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            var d = new StringArgReturningVoidDelegate(SetText);
            _richTextBox.Invoke(d, text);
        }
        else
        {
            _richTextBox.Text += text;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cool Solution. Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 7):

Building on Chaz's answer, in .NET 5 there is [a breaking change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/windows-forms/5.0/automatically-infer-winexe-output-type), so two modifications are required in the project file, i.e. changing `OutputType` and adding `DisableWinExeOutputInference`. Example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows10.0.17763.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
    <Platforms>AnyCPU;x64;x86</Platforms>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Comment: actually, in .NET 6, (and probably earlier on too) just changing the `OutputType` to `Exe` did the trick and created the console... it seems this is the correct answer now, just change it in csproj (or use `/target:exe` instead of `/target:winexe` or whatever) and it will work. All those "set the output type to Console" are basicially doing this under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace SomeProject
{
    class GuiRedirect
    {
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(StandardHandle nStdHandle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool SetStdHandle(StandardHandle nStdHandle, IntPtr handle);
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern FileType GetFileType(IntPtr handle);

    private enum StandardHandle : uint
    {
        Input = unchecked((uint)-10),
        Output = unchecked((uint)-11),
        Error = unchecked((uint)-12)
    }

    private enum FileType : uint
    {
        Unknown = 0x0000,
        Disk = 0x0001,
        Char = 0x0002,
        Pipe = 0x0003
    }

    private static bool IsRedirected(IntPtr handle)
    {
        FileType fileType = GetFileType(handle);

        return (fileType == FileType.Disk) || (fileType == FileType.Pipe);
    }

    public static void Redirect()
    {
        if (IsRedirected(GetStdHandle(StandardHandle.Output)))
        {
            var initialiseOut = Console.Out;
        }

        bool errorRedirected = IsRedirected(GetStdHandle(StandardHandle.Error));
        if (errorRedirected)
        {
            var initialiseError = Console.Error;
        }

        AttachConsole(-1);

        if (!errorRedirected)
            SetStdHandle(StandardHandle.Error, GetStdHandle(StandardHandle.Output));
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine from a command prompt, but not from Start > Run or in Visual Studio. To make it work in all cases, replace the AttachConsole line by:

if (!AttachConsole(-1)) AllocConsole();

If AllocConsole() is called, FreeConsole() should also be called, else the console host continues running after terminating the program.

Comment: What is the intended use of initialiseOut and initialiseError, because they are not used?

Comment: `StandardHandle : uint` is wrong here... should be IntPtr to work both on x86 and x64

Answer (score 3):

Setting the output type as **Console** in the project properties will give you a Console application along with the form you created.

Answer (score 1):

if what you want is simple debug output the following works for me.  I am using VS 2022 programming in C#

add "using System.Diagnostics"

then

```
  Debug.WriteLine("*****");
  Debug.WriteLine(...);
  Debug.WriteLine("");
```

THe output appears in the debug console of VS2022.  There is a lot of stuff there so I use the Debug.WriteLine("*****") and Debug.WriteLine("") to help me find my output.  You can also clear the debug output after start up.

I am still working but running under VS there is no output when running wo debugging

Answer (score 0):

To have both window and console in WinForm application, a working solution (with .Net6.0 and Windows as the targeted OS) is as follows:

```cs
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class MyMainForm : Form
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AllocConsole();
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool FreeConsole();

    private int interval = default;
    
    public MyMainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent(); // default winform designer initialize method
        Invalidate();
        AllocConsole();

        // You can write text to the console within the constructor.
        System.Console.WriteLine("*** Closing the console will close application as well ***");
        this.FormClosing += (s, e) => FreeConsole();
        this.KeyDown += (s, e) => System.Console.WriteLine(interval++);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not just leave it as a Window Forms app, and create a simple form to mimic the Console. The form can be made to look just like the black-screened Console, and have it respond directly to key press.
Then, in the program.cs file, you decide whether you need to Run the main form or the ConsoleForm. For example, I use this approach to capture the command line arguments in the program.cs file. I create the ConsoleForm, initially hide it, then pass the command line strings to an AddCommand function in it, which displays the allowed commands. Finally, if the user gave the -h or -? command, I call the .Show on the ConsoleForm and when the user hits any key on it, I shut down the program. If the user doesn't give the -? command, I close the hidden ConsoleForm and Run the main form.

Comment: i'm not sure this counts as a question.  He gives a complete step-by-step of how to do what he's suggesting, even if actual code would be nice.

Answer (score -3):

You can any time switch between type of applications, to console or windows. So, you will not write special logic to see the stdout. Also, when running application in debugger, you will see all the stdout in output window. You might also just add a breakpoint, and in breakpoint properties change "When Hit...", you can output any messages, and variables. Also you can check/uncheck "Continue execution", and your breakpoint will become square shaped. So, the breakpoint messages without changhing anything in the application in the debug output window.