# Seeing the console's output in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am writing a simple C# program with some outputs (`Console.WriteLine("...");`). The problem is, each time I run it, I cannot see the program's output in the output window.

The "program output" tag is already checked, and I already redirected all outputs to the intermediate window but to no avail.

How do I enable seeing the program's output?

I don't think the problem lies with my code. I tried running a simple program that just outputs a string and readline "ala hello world" and I am still unable to see any output. The problem is either with me looking for the output in the wrong location or Visual Studio acting out.

The `debug.write` method also doesn't work.

Using `debug.Write`, it all works, though it didn't before. Either something bugged out with me before I restarted or I just need to take a break, either way it's all good now. Thanks all for the helpful comments =)

Comment: Visual Studio is covering your console window.  Move it to your other monitor.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I show a console output/window in a forms application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-a-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application)

Answer (score 196, accepted):

You can use the [`System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.write.aspx) or `System.Runtime.InteropServices` method to write messages to the Output Window.

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write (in case the OP doesn't have the namespace in play)

Comment: Ah true, I'm just to used to hiting control + period :)

Comment: jonsca: i have a namespace in play and why can i just use console.writeline, i want my program to write to the console its not only for testing reasons??

Comment: If your application is a console application you can use console.writeline to print to the console window or if you application is a windows form app you can use debug.write. Check this link for abit more info http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/701e02cc-ad77-46b9-b4fc-410bb3ff7a0d

Comment: interesting didn't know that, and yes my app is a windows form app, but no i tried using debug.Write method same problem, it compiles and all is peachy but am unable to see the output anywhere

Comment: I'm sure you are but just to confirm you are running the application in debug mode via VS (F5 or Debug->Start Debugging)?

Comment: I'm getting `Error: identifier "System" is undefined`

Answer (score 51):

Here are a couple of things to check:

1. For `console.Write/WriteLine`, your app must be a console application. (right-click the project in Solution Explorer, choose **Properties**, and look at the "**Output Type**" combo in the Application Tab -- should be "**Console Application**" (note, if you really need a windows application or a class library, don't change this to Console App just to get the `Console.WriteLine`).
2. You could use `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine` to write to the output window (to show the output window in VS, got to **View** | **Output**)  Note that these writes will only occur in a build where the DEBUG conditional is defined (by default, debug builds define this, and release builds do not)
3. You could use `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Writeline` if you want to be able to write to configurable "listeners" in non-debug builds. (by default, this writes to the Output Window in Visual Studio, just like `Debug.Writeline`)

Comment: I wasn't seeing my output, but then realized that I had to run the program in debug mode (F5) instead of Ctrl + Shift + F5. Thanks!

Comment: System.Diagnostics.Trace.Writeline doesn't seem to work though, is there something else I need to configure for this?

Comment: «1» — false statement. Mono shows the output fine for all applications. «2» — ofc. The problem is that the method doesn't outputs to the terminal too. So one can not debug an app on the PC without an IDE.

Answer (score 34):

Add a `Console.Read();` at the end of your program. It'll keep the application from closing, and you can see its output that way.

This is a console application I just dug up that stops after processing but before exiting:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DummyObjectList dol = new DummyObjectList(2);
        dol.Add(new DummyObject("test1", (Decimal)25.36));
        dol.Add(new DummyObject("test2", (Decimal)0.698));
        XmlSerializer dolxs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DummyObjectList));
        dolxs.Serialize(Console.Out, dol);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);

        List<DummyObject> dolist = new List<DummyObject>(2);
        dolist.Add(new DummyObject("test1", (Decimal)25.36));
        dolist.Add(new DummyObject("test2", (Decimal)0.698));
        XmlSerializer dolistxs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<DummyObject>));
        dolistxs.Serialize(Console.Out, dolist);
        Console.Read(); //  <--- Right here
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can simply add a breakpoint on the last line.

Comment: Console.ReadLine works as well you just have to hit enter to continue where as Read takes any standard key.

Comment: its a windows form app, and debug.write nor console.writeline method seem to work

Comment: Euhm, why are you outputting to the console from a Windows Form app? I suggest outputting on a form or dialgbox instead. Or make a console app...

Comment: yea that was already pointed out to me, its a just a stupid mistake on my part, still thanks for the heads up =)

Comment: The Console.Read() causes the console window to get focus, and hence appear in front of VS. If you simply put a break point in after a Console.Write() the Console window will show your output but does not have focus so may not be visible.

Answer (score 21):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to run the program instead of <kbd>F5</kbd>.

Comment: Ctrl + F5 starts the application without debugging to you wont see anything in the output window.

Comment: This worked for me; I just wanted to see what the program was outputting, none of the console output was showing up. This caused it to keep the console window open after running so I could see the output.

Comment: +1, this is the one, if you don't actually want to debug (shows the console, and allows to read the output).

Answer (score 8):

`System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()` will work, but you have to be looking in the right place for the output. In Visual Studio 2010, on the menu bar, click *Debug* -> *Windows* -> *Output*. Now, at the bottom of the screen docked next to your error list, there should be an output tab. Click it and double check it's showing output from the debug stream on the dropdown list.

P.S.: I think the output window shows on a fresh install, but I can't remember. If it doesn't, or if you closed it by accident, follow these instructions.

Answer (score 0):

To keep open your windows console and to not use other output methods rather than the standard output stream cout go to Name-of-your-project -> Properties -> Linker -> System.

Once there, select the SubSytem Tab and mark Console (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE). Once you have done this, whenever you want to compile use Ctrl + F5 (Start without debugging) and your console will keep opened. :)

Comment: I think it's applicable to C++, not to C# as in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this frequently for some reason, and I can't fathom why this solution hasn't been mentioned:

**Click *View* → *Output* (or just hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and hit W > O)**

Console output then appears where your *Error List*, *Locals*, and *Watch* windows are.

*Note: I'm using Visual Studio 2015.*

Comment: The Output window you mention looks like it is generated by the debugger since it has lots of lines relating to assemblies being loaded, threads starting and stopping etcetera.  This is different than console output.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is by itself covering the console window, try minimizing Visual Studio window they are drawn over each other.

Answer (score -1):

In Program.cs, between:

```
static int Main(string[] agrs)
{
```

and the rest of your code, add:

```
#if DEBUG
    int rtn = Main2(args);
    Console.WriteLine("return " + rtn);
    Console.WriteLine("ENTER to continue.");
    Console.Read();
    return rtn;
}

static int Main2(string[] args)
{
#endif
```

Comment: Please add a description, how your code solves the problem.

Answer (score -4):

You could create 2 small methods, one that can be called at the beginning of the program, the other at the end. You could also use Console.Read(), so that the program doesn't close after the last write line.

This way you can determine when your functionality gets executed and also when the program exists.

```
startProgram()
{
     Console.WriteLine("-------Program starts--------");
     Console.Read();
}


endProgram()
{
    Console.WriteLine("-------Program Ends--------");
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this answer brings new information to the question since the Console.Read() possibility has already been stated before.