# Console.Writeline c# not working

Tags: windows-7, macos, visual-studio-2008, c#

I am interested in programming c# in visual studio and I have a problem here. I have a mac book pro and installed parallel 7 and then windows 7. now I have visual studio 2008 installed on the machine but when i try to execute the command Console.Writeline, console would not stay open. it would just execute the command and in less than a second closes it down. is there any solution that I can use to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

A console application exist after it exists the `Main()` method, that's most likely why the console window is getting closed immediately.

Try running the application using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>, or add `Console.ReadLine()` at the end of your `Main()` method.

Comment: Agreed. I usually wrap my last ReadLine() in #if DEBUG and #endif, so it only happens while building the Debug version.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your application in debug mode with a breakpoint on the last line to get it to pause so you can read the console output.

This is a pretty common issue with Visual Studio development in all languages and there are several other ways around it.  See the answers to the following questions on Stack Overflow for more options:

- [Visual Studio Console App - Prevent window from closing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1775865/1288)
- [How to make Visual Studio Pause after executing a console app in debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/193469/1288)
- [Seeing the console's output in Visual Studio 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5301232/1288)