# Writing output to the console from a c# winforms application

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, console

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I show console output/window in a forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application)

Is there a way for a c# winforms program to write to the console window?

Comment: Nice post, but it's already been asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Unless I'm missing something, that post doesn't address the redirection issue ...

Comment: What redirection issue?  You didn't say anything about that in your question.  Ah, I see; you self-answered.  Well, unless you're expecting additional answers from others...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are basically two things that can happen here.

1. Console output

It is possible for a winforms program to attach itself to the console window that created it (or to a different console window, or indeed to a new console window if desired). Once attached to the console window Console.WriteLine() etc works as expected. One gotcha to this approach is that the program returns control to the console window immediately, and then carries on writing to it, so the user can also type away in the console window. You can use start with the /wait parameter to handle this I think.

[Start commsnd syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=net-7.0)

2. Redirected console output

This is when someone pipes the output from your program  somewhere else, eg.

yourapp > file.txt

Attaching to a console window in this case effectively ignores the piping. To make this work you can call Console.OpenStandardOutput() to get a handle to the stream that the output should be piped to. This only works if the output is piped, so if you want to handle both of the scenarios you need to open the standard output and write to it and attach to the console window. This does mean that the output is sent to the console window **and** to the pipe but its the best solution I could find. Below the code I use to do this.

```
// This always writes to the parent console window and also to a redirected stdout if there is one.
// It would be better to do the relevant thing (eg write to the redirected file if there is one, otherwise
// write to the console) but it doesn't seem possible.
public class GUIConsoleWriter : IConsoleWriter
{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    private static extern bool AttachConsole(int dwProcessId);

    private const int ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS = -1;

    StreamWriter _stdOutWriter;
  
    // this must be called early in the program
    public GUIConsoleWriter()
    {
        // this needs to happen before attachconsole.
        // If the output is not redirected we still get a valid stream but it doesn't appear to write anywhere
        // I guess it probably does write somewhere, but nowhere I can find out about
        var stdout = Console.OpenStandardOutput();
        _stdOutWriter = new StreamWriter(stdout);
        _stdOutWriter.AutoFlush = true;

        AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS);
    }

    public void WriteLine(string line)
    {
        _stdOutWriter.WriteLine(line);
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: You could read a command line option to specify whether to write to standard output or the console