# How to make winforms gui app to write to console

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I have a gui application.

I start it from a console (windows cmd).

Is there way to write something to console from the application?

I tried `Console.WriteLine()` and `Debug.WriteLine()`, but it doesn't work: I see that messages in *Output* window in VisualStudio, but not in `cmd / PowerShell`.

Comment: So you have two applications, one forms and one console?

Comment: @TaW no, I have only one gui application. But I start it from cmd window.

Comment: You would have to find the/a cmd process window handle  and inject text there. - Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25772622/how-do-i-echo-into-an-existing-cmd-window) is of interest.

Comment: @John: There is no console application. Only gui one. But I start it not from Visual Studio or Windows explorer but from console (window cmd or powershell)

Comment: You could change your projects outputtype  (target) to [exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/target-exe-compiler-option), that gives you a console that you can write to with Console.WriteLine()

Comment: @rene: Exactly! Please, post an answer, I'll respectfully accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The best solution would be the simplest one. Create a Windows Form project and then change the output type to console application:

**Project Properties -> Application -> Output Type -> Console Application**

then you will have the `Console.WriteLine` to work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated already, you could change the project to be a Console application by right clicking on the Project and clicking on the Project Properties > Application > Output Type. Then you can set this to Console application and have the ability to use `Console.WriteLine`.

**However**, if this is plainly for debugging, consider using `Debug.WriteLine` (which will write to the debut console inside of Visual Studio).

Finally, if you just want a convenient and easy way to display messages like you can in the console, look into `MessageBox.Show`