# Lines are not inserted in List<T>

Tags: c#

Why doesn't my collection of strings (`lst`) appear in the console? Visual Studio does not show any obvious errors. Please point out my mistake.

```
public partial class Home : Page {
    public Home() {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // ...

    private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Home.ABC();
        MessageBox.Show("hello world");
    }

    static void ABC() {
        List<string> lst = new List<string>();
        OpenFileDialog opendialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        opendialog.Multiselect = true;
        bool? dialogResult = opendialog.ShowDialog();
        if (dialogResult.HasValue && dialogResult.Value) {
            foreach (var file in opendialog.Files) {
                Stream fileStream = file.OpenRead();
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream)) {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream) {
                        string line=reader.ReadLine();
                        lst.Add(line);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine(lst);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The message box shows `hello world`, so the function `ABC()` also runs?

[image]

Comment: What sort of project is this? If it's Windows Forms / WPF, it doesn't *have* a console attached to it...

Comment: better if you debug yourself and ask by telling the error

Comment: Does lst contain anything by the time 'Hello World' shows?

Comment: Such code. Very it. Much edit. Wow

Comment: Console I used here for illustrative purposes. Maybe I can not use here.I added the picture.maybe it will say something???

Comment: You added an image: When you debug the `lst.Add()` line, the statement has not yet executed and the line has not yet been added to `lst`. Therefore, `lst` appears empty.

Comment: As an aside, this line does not do what you think it does:  `Console.WriteLine(lst);`

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you are not using a console application and as such you cannot write to the console.

Create a RichTextBox and use

```
foreach(var line in lst)
{
    RichTextBoxName.AppendText(line)
}

foreach(var line in lst)
    {
        RichTextBoxName.AppendText(line + "\n") //adds a new line after each string
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a console window in a standard Winforms application. It is launched with Application.Run and shows the default dialog, rather than the console.

In order to display a console window AS WELL as a winforms dialog, you have to use Win32 API to manually create the console window.

See here:

[How do I show a console output/window in a forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-a-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application)

Answer (score 0):

The console stream output isn't set to a visible console window, so Console.Write accepts the text, but doesn't display anything anywhere.

Try using [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.