# How can I add multiple terminals in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

Can we add multiple different terminals in Visual Studio Code?

I am planning to add following three terminals and work with all of these:

> 1. Windows Command prompt
> 2. PowerShell
> 3. Git Bash

I know I need to add the following command in *Preferences* → *Setting*:

```
 // // 64-bit cmd if available, otherwise 32-bit
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe",
// // 64-bit PowerShell if available, otherwise 32-bit
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
// // Git Bash
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

I want to add all of the above three commands in `setting.json`

[image]

And when I click **`+`** different terminal should open and I want to work with those terminals without changing the preferences.
Is it possible in Visual Studio Code or not?

Comment: If you type this into the powershell terminal it will launch the git bash: `& "c:\Program Files\git\bin\bash.exe"`

Comment: Related post - [How to change the integrated terminal in visual studio code or VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40487445/465053)

Comment: As of https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_35 you can now do this more easily, see my answer totally at the bottom of the page. I ended here via google, installed the extension, then read all the way down, noticed the comment by Neil, then went to the release note of may 2019 and added it here as a fyi

Comment: In 2022 the most appropriate answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/69748852/7992600

Answer (score 119, accepted):

There is a way to make this happens with these steps by installing an extension:

1. Find an extension called *Shell launcher* and install it or you can find it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher).  Reload Visual Studio Code if you want or after you finished all steps.
2. Go to *Files* → *Preferences* → *Settings* and this will open the *settings.json* file and you then insert this (you can edit this to your heart's content):

Code:

```
"shellLauncher.shells.windows": [
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\<sysnative>\\cmd.exe",
        "label": "cmd"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\<sysnative>\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
        "label": "PowerShell"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "label": "Git bash"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\<sysnative>\\bash.exe",
        "label": "WSL Bash"
    }
]
```

PS: You can use `shellLauncher.shells.linux` for [Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux) or `shellLauncher.shells.osx` for [macOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS).

3. Go to *Files* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts* and then find on the `{}` icon on the top right corner to open the *[keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization)* file.  Insert this:

Code:

```
[
    { "key": "ctrl+alt+`", "command": "shellLauncher.launch" }
]
```

Type *shelllauncher* into the search bar. You can then see the *Shell Launcher: Launch* command. Highlight and use any keybinding you like. For example, I picked <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) for myself.

You can reload your Visual Studio Code and click the key combination you have assigned and that will give you the option to choose which integrated terminal you want to use.

[image]

For more details, please check the official site: *[Shell launcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher)*

Comment: this is not working. I want to add multiple `terminal.integrated.shell.windows` not `Shell launcher`

Comment: I don't think this can be done right now but maybe in the future as Ben pointed out.  This is just a work around to have multiple terminals by installing an extension with some tweaks so you can have cmd, powershell or bash opened at the same time.

Comment: Man this is really cool extension and actually is really what I need because sometimes I need a bash and multiple PS.
Great!

Comment: For those who'll be copy/paste settings. If you are on Windows machine in your paths replace `sysnative` to `System32`

Comment: Works great. Although I would prefer the solution with integrated options if any working.

Comment: Also if 32bit vscode is used on 64bit windows it will not work! There is a [bug](https://github.com/Tyriar/vscode-shell-launcher/issues/28)

Comment: Unfortunately you can not split your terminals though.

Comment: @nullmn, check this out. https://i.stack.imgur.com/ADwea.png. The plus sign and the split screen sign on the top right corner of the terminal window should help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I click the split button VS Code will simply open the default terminal to the side. I want to be able to choose which one opens on the side.

Comment: @nullmn, sorry I forgot to answer your question. I was able to do that and here is a screenshot to show you (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lauMc.png). Basically, there is no issue to open the first terminal which you can have anything you want. Then you click the `+` to add a new terminal that you want. Now you need to select back to the first terminal in the drop down field, then you can click the `split screen` sign. That should give what you want. Try and let me know.

Comment: @ReZ, did you install the extension? You can also find it here (https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher)

Comment: Didn't work for me. None of the configured shells are showing up. Looks like the configuration settings have no effect on the plugin.

Comment: In 2022 the most appropriate answer is https://stackoverflow.com/a/69748852/7992600

Answer (score 76):

Here is a simple, suitable and complete answer while as a development I need multiple terminals handy in a click like below:

[image]

And I don't bother about their path, add another extension for what Visual Studio Code is already capable of or reload VS Shell, etc. and go to insert and set up the settings files manually.

I found this question is asked many times and almost all landed up manually setup of write some settings, etc. or sometimes only opted to get a single type of terminal. The [answer of Pawan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427631/how-can-i-add-multiple-terminals-in-visual-studio-code/50288696#50288696) is somewhat near, but again that solution finally land up to a single terminal, going to command setup for switch terminal and this one will work for Git or any other terminal.

If you have tools installed which worked on command line like PowerShell and Git along with the default [cmd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe) prompt in Windows then the following quick three steps to get all terminals at once and switch to anyone with a click.

1. Open terminal. It should be visible (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> (backtick) or from menu *View* → *Integrated Terminal*)
2. Open commands search (use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or from menu *View* → *Command Palette...*)
3. In the command box, type *"Terminal: Select Default Shell"* to select this option from the drop down.

   [image]
4. As you select this option, then all the available commands which are in path will be listed below like below

   [image]
5. Just click any one which you like to add for quick access from the command list.
6. Finally, in the terminal window, just click on the `+` sign next to the terminal list as shown below:

   [image]

   The terminal selected in step 5 will now be added after performing step 6 to the list without removal of the earlier terminal.
7. Repeat step 3-6 for adding any other terminal to the command list.

To work with a particular terminal, just select the required one in the terminal list of the terminal window.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for though I accidentally discovered it. :)

Comment: This approach will overwrite default terminal every time new view is added. If Visual Studio code is used for other purposes where default terminal should remain same, this is not preferable approach.

Comment: Thanks...exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Is there a way to make the settings stick? It looks like the setting goes away on browser close.

Comment: Thank you. I like native solutions.

Comment: Not the solution. I want to fire up VSCode and get to work. I know this is a work around, but it requires a bunch of steps. I want to, like the OP suggests, just have the options right there. They've located the spot. What it should be is an array, perhaps with a preferred or default to open to. But, I want what the OP says.
I want every session to have the dropdown populated without all the trickery.

Comment: To be fair, this answer would have used what I've added below if it were available at the time. Now, the dropdown on the terminal window includes `Select Default Shell`.

Answer (score 27):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd> shortcut, or press a cross sign to run a new terminal. Then type *bash* if your default mode is PowerShell or *powershell* if your default mode is [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29). And here you are, your terminal is switched.

Comment: This does work well, but it doesn't carry over between VSCode sessions since it doesn't make any changes to settings. 
Personally I like this since it's only a couple of key strokes and I don't always need multiple terminal types.

Comment: This is the best solution so far

Comment: I came here looking for exactly this answer, thank you!  I wish hovering over the `+` would show the keyboard shortcut!

Answer (score 7):

For now, Visual Studio Code supports defining only one of available terminals as the default at a time, and you can not add multiple shell terminals.

If you don't want to install the "Shell Launcher" plugin as suggested by @ian0411 then here is a quick way to change/select default terminal.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette).

Type "Terminal: Select Default Shell" and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. You will be prompted to select Git Bash, PowerShell or Cmd as shown below:

[image: Option to change preferred terminal shell]

**Note:** This will change the default shell terminal, but there isn't any harm changing it whenever you need to use another.

BTW, if you need to switch only between Cmd & PowerShell, then you can type *cmd* or *powershell* (in an already-opened terminal) to switch to the desired terminal. But it would not work for Git Bash.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see this in the previous answers, but I read all the answers. I think this is the best approach for what is supported right now. I believe, like myself, the OP simply wants to open Visual Studio Code, and down there on the terminal window, we just want a list of options to open from.

Yes, you can open the command, "Terminal: Select Default Shell" and loop through that to add various types of terminals...

[image: Yes, you can open the command, "Terminal: Select Default Shell" and loop through that to add various types of terminals...]

Followed by:

[image]

I don't know when this option was added to the dropdown, *but look!* There isn't any need to start by looking up the command. I think this is a lot smoother than any other answer, but it still results in the annoying overwrite of your default terminal to whatever your last choice was before leaving session.

Here, we can more easily open the **Select Default Shell**. It should support *"Select New Shell"*. Simple, you'd think. Hopefully someone adds that soon or I have time to contribute.

[image: Here, we can more easily open the "Select Default Shell" - it should support "Select New Shell"]

Comment: Select new shell with a different type is what I was looking for too.

Answer (score 4):

As of [version 1.35](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_35), you can now:

1. select "Select Default Shell" from the pulldown menu directly above the terminal
2. select the one you like
3. click the `+`
4. done

(The same goes for opening the split screen: before this, do 1 + 2 and then click the split screen button.)

(Although it is overriding the default, but it does no longer matter if this is your flow.)

Answer (score 4):

I'm fairly certain that these are old-style *[settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file)* and won't work as discussed in Visual Studio Code 2021.  The new style looks like:

```
...
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows":
{   "Bash":
    {    "path": ["C:\\Programs\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"],
         "icon": "terminal-bash",
    },
    "Command Prompt":
    {   "path": ["${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"],
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "PowerShell":
    {   "path":  ["C:\\Programs\\PowerShell\\pwsh.exe"],
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "args": [],
        "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
},
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Bash"
...
```

That will get you access to Command and PowerShell and set [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) as the default shell (my preference).  If you want to launch a standalone application like [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), you will need something else.

Comment: I would say that now this is the most appropriate answer as of 2022

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by adding a different key at the end. By just changing your example to:

```
// // 64-bit cmd if available, otherwise 32-bit
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe",
// // 64-bit PowerShell if available, otherwise 32-bit
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows2": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
// // Git Bash
 "terminal.integrated.shell.windows3": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
```

Note that the key **...shell.windows** is changed to *...shell.windows2* and *...shell.windows3*.

Follow-up finding: I've noticed that once restart of the IDE, only the first terminal gets displayed. I had to reopen the settings and save it once to get both the terminals again. Will post if any better solution available.

Comment: I added these settings to UserSetting, but there's a warning on the 2nd & 3th shells, the message of warning is "Unknown configuration setting"

Answer (score 1):

In the terminal tab, there's a Split Terminal button. It works like a charm.

Comment: It's not what was asked.

Answer (score 1):

To open *multiple* terminals, please check the screenshot for the same (on the right bottom of the Visual Studio Code there will be a dropdown and just after it, there is the `+` (plus) icon. On pressing it, the new terminal will open.).

[image]

Comment: The screenshot is practically ***unreadable***. Can you resize the window first, etc. and resubmit it? (But *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***[without](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/131011)*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today.)

Answer (score 1):

The recommended way to automatically open multiple terminal windows is to use the **Tasks feature**. See [Automating launching of terminals](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_automating-launching-of-terminals) in the Visual Studio Code documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For WSL Ubuntu on Windows terminal:

File -> preferences -> settings -> click code icon in top right

Enter the following:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\wsl.exe",
    "git.enableSmartCommit": true
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use VSCode to do remote SSH where the destination IP & PORT are dynamic. I have a requirement to connect to remote serverB via serverA. When I login to serverA, I am redirected to serverB based on sshd_configs on serverA. when I do ssh via cmd line it goes fine to serverB. But VSCode is not able to do that. Any ideas?