# How to select a different type of command shell in the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal?

Tags: shell, terminal, visual-studio-code

I looked at [this](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) link which talks about changing the default command shell in the integrated terminal of Visual Studio Code. I was able to change it to Git Bash using the below setting in the **settings.json** file. You can open **settings.json** file by pressing the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> or from **File** → **Preferences** → **Settings** menu:

```
{
   "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
}
```

There is a <kbd>+</kbd> sign in the integrated terminal with the help of which you can have multiple terminals running parallelly as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

I want to load a Git Bash shell in terminal # 1, Windows PowerShell in terminal # 2, and so on. What is the relevant configuration to achieve it?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427631/how-to-add-multiple-terminal-in-vs-code/50890703#50890703 for answer your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of June 17 '2018, things have become really smooth in Visual Studio (VS) Code when it comes to changing the integrated command shell. I'm enlisting all the options here:

1. **Select a different command shell on the go** - Name of the command shell is itself a command to switch the current command shell to the target command shell. For example, let's say my integrated command shell is currently showing Bash, and I want to switch to PowerShell. Then type **powershell** command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. The command shell will change to PowerShell. Similarly it works for all other types of command shells installed in VS Code.
2. **More instances of command shell** - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>`(back-tick)</kbd>. Every time you press the keyboard shortcut combination, a new instance of the command shell will get added.
3. **Change the configuration of default command shell type** - Press <kbd>F1</kbd> in Visual Studio Code and type or select **Terminal: Select Default Shell** as shown in the snapshot below.

[image: Terminal Selection]

Once selected, then choose the default command shell of your choice to change the settings permanently:

[image: Terminal Selection]

Comment: On Windows (_VS Code version - 1.45.1_), I noticed that the `Name of the command shell is itself a command to switch the current command shell to the target command shell` seems to be switching among all 3 standard command shells (i.e. cmd, powershell, bash) only when the `bash` is set as default shell otherwise it only switches between cmd and powershell but not to the bash with the following error `'bash' is not recognized`.

Answer (score 12):

No need to keep changing your default terminal setting. Install the [Shell Launcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher) extension, configure it, and then `ctrl-shift-t` to select which terminal you want to open inside of VS Code.

[image: Screenshot of Shell Launcher and settings]

Answer (score 2):

In recent version (1.15.0) you can

- change the settings, then run the terminal, you've set
- then change the settings again and run the another type of terminal by pressing the `+` sign
- and so on...

You can put this in your settings file, and uncomment which one you need.

```
// 64-bit cmd if available, otherwise 32-bit
//"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\cmd.exe"
// 64-bit PowerShell if available, otherwise 32-bit
//"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
// Git Bash
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"
// Bash on Ubuntu (on Windows)
//"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\sysnative\\bash.exe"
```

Comment: Ohh..interesting. In fact your suggestion is working in pretty older versions of VS code as well e.g. 1.9. I tested it just now. I always thought it is a single configuration and I never bothered to click the `+` sign just after changing the configuration. Instead, I used to restart Visual Studio code to see the configuration changes to take effect in the terminal. Wonderful answer!

Answer (score 1):

Terminal profiles is what you are looking for - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/terminal/profiles. It didn't exist by the time the question was posted and the only solution by that time was the somewhat limited "terimnal.integrated.terminal.xxx" solution.

Example configuration:

```
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
  "Cmd": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "icon": "terminal-cmd"
  },
  "GitBash": {
    "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe", "icon": "terminal-bash",
    "icon": "terminal-bash"
  },
  "PowerShell": {
    "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
    "icon": "terminal-powershell"
  },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Click on Arrow then click something like Select template profile
so then , will Open the search bar automatically, so... change by your choice