# Change the default terminal in Visual Studio Code

Tags: bash, powershell, cmd, terminal, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on my Windows 10 PC. I want to change my default terminal from Windows [PowerShell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PowerShell) to [Bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) on [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) ([on Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux)).

How can I do that?

Comment: Related post here - [How to use multiple types of command shell in Visual Studio code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44425545/465053)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select a different type of command shell in the Visual Studio Code integrated terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425545/how-to-select-a-different-type-of-command-shell-in-the-visual-studio-code-integr)

Comment: Re *"on Windows"*: [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux), presumably?

Answer (score 737, accepted):

You can also select your default terminal by pressing <kbd>F1</kbd> in Visual Studio Code and typing/selecting **`Terminal: Select Default Profile`** (or **`Terminal: Select Default Shell`** in older Visual Studio Code versions).

[image: Terminal Selection 3]

Older:

[image: Terminal Selection]

[image: Terminal Selection]

Comment: As of today on MacOS the Terminal extension does not have a "Select Default Shell" option in the menu! Lucky for me using https://stackoverflow.com/a/49916667/99834 worked.

Comment: I'm using MacOS Catalina right now, "Terminal: Select Default Shell" was there and worked for me.

Comment: Updated Answer for Linux and MAC: https://askubuntu.com/a/1118140/810954

Comment: Has this changed because I have done this on Windows version 1.65.2 and every time there is a restart, I get the powershell instead of Git bash

Comment: 2023: ```>select terminal profile``` is the command

Comment: For macOS users, just type the key **SHIFT** + **Command** + **P** and type **terminal profile**. **Choose Terminal: Select Default Profile** and choose your preferred terminal.

Answer (score 102):

Configure your default integrated terminal by running the Terminal: **Select Default Profile** command, which is also accessible via the terminal dropdown.

[image]

See *[Terminal Basics](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_terminal-profiles)*.

Comment: This is the correct and most recent way of doing it, however, it doesn't work for me in VS Code v1.56.2. This works "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe"

Comment: When im trying to use "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe" Im getting this warning - "This is deprecated, the new recommended way to configure your default shell is by creating a terminal profile" (VS Code v1.56.2)

Comment: I’m getting the same deprecated warning but at least it works. Like I said recommended way isn’t working for me on v1.56.2.

Comment: Not work for me in VSCode 1.56.2 too. Use deprecated way, it works.

Comment: There is a Small drop down that says Select Default Profile... that sets the current shell as the default profile.

Comment: Not working in VSCode 1.57.1, HOWEVER, if you remove "source": "Git Bash" AND change the name from "Git Bash" to something like "GitBash", it works. Is there a bug???

Answer (score 55):

I just type the following keywords in the opened terminal;

1. powershell
2. bash
3. cmd
4. node
5. python (or python3)

See details in the below image (Visual Studio Code version 1.19.1 on the [Windows 10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10) OS):

[image]

It works on Visual Studio Code Mac as well. I tried it with Visual Studio Code (version 1.20.1).

Comment: Seems to work only when `bash` is selected as default shell.

Comment: Was searching for a way to open my wsl on windows without changing the default, creating new, then switching default back to powershell. Simply typing `wsl` works an absolute charm

Answer (score 40):

Go to menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Settings* (or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>). Then click the leftmost icon in the top right corner, "Open Settings (JSON)"

[image: Screenshot showing location of icon]

In the JSON settings window, add this (within the curly braces `{}`):

```
"terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\WINDOWS\\System32\\bash.exe"`
```

(Here you can put any other custom settings you want as well.)

Checkout that path to make sure your *bash.exe* file is there. Otherwise, find out where it is and point to that path instead.

Now if you open a new terminal window in Visual Studio Code, it should open with Bash instead of PowerShell.

Comment: It appears that VSCode has changed a little since this answer, now there is a button with {} on it that you must press to get to the editor to make this change. The command in this answer did work correctly. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: You should not use the executable from System32 since (normally) vs code has no access to that executable. Instead use the program files one `terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe"`

Comment: `"terminal.integrated.shell.windows"` or `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux"` is deprecated and it did not seem to work in my case (v1.62.0 on linux). Use `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows"` or `"terminal.integrated.shell.linux"` instead and define the executable path in the `"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows"` or `"terminal.integrated.profiles.linux"`, repectively. See also @Stephanieraymos answer below.

Comment: I have `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux` and `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` and `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx`. The magic three..

Answer (score 25):

1. Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>
2. Search "**Terminal: Select Default Profile**". Click
3. You will see terminals options and select **Git Bash**

Answer (score 6):

You can change the terminal by opening the [Command Palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette) by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.

Or you can go to *View* at the top and click "Open Command Palette".

Then type *Terminal: Select Default Profile*

And you can type which terminal you want.

Answer (score 6):

To change the default terminal for your project in Visual Studio Code:

1. Create a folder by name of  *.vscode*
2. Create a *settings.json* file in this folder:
3. Write the settings you want

For example, if you are a Windows user and want to set "Command Prompt" as the default terminal you can write:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt"
```

values. You can pass: `"Git Bash"`, `"PowerShell"`, and `"Command Prompt"`.

For Linux, you will use `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux` and for macOS you will use: `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx`

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Since you use WSL, Visual Studio Code has the dedicated [Remote - WSL](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-wsl) extension, so you can use a Linux environment directly in Visual Studio Code.

When you open the project inside Linux, by default, it's using the Linux default shell (bash by default), so no configuration needed.

If you want to switch to other profile, there is *Terminal* → *Integrated* → *Default Profile: Linux* section, so you can pick your favorite one.

[image: Linux Terminal Profiles]

Comment: It should be the correct answer, because the OP wants to switch from Windows to Linux in Vscode which is only possible with Remote WSL I guess.

Comment: I set fish as default shell on wsl, but vscode still used bash. Set this setting explicitly and now it works like a charms, ty!

Answer (score 4):

Going off of [arielhad's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/change-the-default-terminal-in-visual-studio-code/67501013#67501013)...

My Visual Studio Code version was 1.57.1.

**Open the [settings.json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65908987/how-can-i-open-visual-studio-codes-settings-json-file) file:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>p</kbd>
- Type 'Open Settings (JSON)' and select.

**Add the following:**

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
        ],
        "source": "PowerShell",
        "icon": "terminal-powershell",
        "args": [
            "-NoLogo",
            "-ExecutionPolicy",
            "Bypass"
        ]
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
        "path": [
            "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
            "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
        ],
        "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },

//START: THIS DOES NOT WORK
    "Git Bash": {
        "path": [
            "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        ],
        "source": "Git Bash",
        "icon": "terminal-bash"
    }
// END: THIS DOES NOT WORK

//START: THIS WORKS
    "GitBash": {
        "path": [
            "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        ],
        "icon": "terminal-bash"
    }
// END: THIS WORKS
}
```

I don't know why the second way works, but it does. It appears the 'Git Bash' is a reserved name and I guess you cannot set the path.

Answer (score 2):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. Then type *settings.json*.

At the end of the file, change the 'PowerShell' to 'Git Bash'.

Comment: Lol, what makes this answer different from @OneShadow 's answer. Please elaborate more on it.

Answer (score 2):

The integrated shell option still works, but it has been deprecated. The fix is to use the integrated profile instead:

```
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
        "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe (migrated)": {
            "path": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
            "args": []
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the type of console, you can write this in the file *[keybindings.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization)* (this file can be found in the following path: menu *File* → *Preferences* → *Keyboard Shortcuts*)

```javascript
// With this, you can select what type of console you want
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+t",
    "command": "shellLauncher.launch"
},

// And this will help you quickly change console
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+j",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusNext"
},
{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+k",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.focusPrevious"
}
```

Comment: Without this extension [Shell launcher](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Tyriar.shell-launcher) this answer is useless. So just install it and specify shortcut.
Be careful, this shortcut is already defined - find this shortcut and check if you use action under this shortcut or not.