# why does vscode execute my selection so slowly in python console?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

This has been annoying me for weeks, it's usually not this bad but it's honestly like a snail at this point.

I can either run a specific line, or select some code and run the selection which sends that selection to the python console.

Why does this happen so slowly? See the gif...

[image: why]

Any thoughts on how I could fix this?

Comment: Which platform?

Comment: windows 10 64bit

Comment: Have you tried a different IDE?

Comment: Yes I used to use spyder but it had so many issues (i.e. freezing, crashing, code collapsing errors, matplotlib backend issues, etc.) that I jumped ship - quite happy with VSCode minus this..

Comment: How much text are you sending to the terminal? That looks like a ton which could cause buffering issues. I would say that if you're sending more than 5 lines at a time you may want to look at a different workflow like using the interactive window.

Comment: it's weird, sometimes I can send as many as I want and it runs almost instantly, sometimes it will happen like this with even 1 line

Answer (score 2):

## Two Solutions:

1) Well first one is that you can try by changing the default terminal `Powershell` to `Command Prompt`

Here are the two guide for you on how to change the terminal

[Guide 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/vscode-change-default-terminal/45899693)

[Guide 2](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuration)

---

2) Start `VSCode` with the `--ignore-gpu-blacklist` flag and see if it solve any performance issues