# How to Make VS Code Terminal Run Ubuntu Mac?

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, visual-studio-code

Hello I'm using a mac and how do I setup the terminal that comes with vs-code to use Ubuntu? (basically same commands that are used in the mac terminal) I'm new guys so please go easy on me.

[image]

Comment: Do you want change from zsh shell to bash shell? @jr005

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/vscode-change-default-terminal/45899693#:~:text=You%20can%20also%20select%20your,selecting%20Terminal%3A%20Select%20Default%20Shell.)

Comment: This tell how to change the default shell of the terminal @jr005

Comment: It worked thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You might want to utilize tools like [vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) & virtualbox.
You setup ubuntu on that virtual machine,
Then you connect your vs code to the vm, using [Remote SSH extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh).

You can read the full instructions here:
https://sedigit.com/2021/abetobing/02-debugging-using-vs-code-inside-vagrant
and here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/ssh