# VSCODE default terminal is still powershell

Tags: visual-studio-code

After I `Select Default Profile` to WSL, I have this configuration line `"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Ubuntu-20.04 (WSL)"` in `settings.json`. Then when I open VSCODE, the terminal is still `powershell`, only when I open a `New Terminal`, it appears to be the `WSL` shell, did I miss any configuration? I thought the terminal should be `WSL` even when I open VSCODE.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode Change Default Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/vscode-change-default-terminal)

Comment: @Faisal No, it does not. If you read my questions, I have already use that to set the default profile, and it will work only after I opened the terminal and add new one. The terminal when I open VSCODE is still powershell.

Comment: Are you running v1.57?  And did that fix it?  Try to open another terminal, close the powershell terminal and reload or restart vscode.

Comment: @Mark, just checked, the issue is gone (VSCODE is upgraded to `1.57` recently), thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note this [error came back in VSCode 1.60 (Aug. 2021)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69056079/6309), and was (almost) fixed in 1.60.1.

However... You now have: "[on reload, an extra terminal is getting created](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/133128) "

[image: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/29464607/133345067-d4ea8242-3845-48d4-a7e7-5c08ff26a7b3.gif]

This will be fixed in VSCode 1.61 (Sept. 2021)