# Vs code terminal changes to powershell every time

Tags: powershell, terminal, visual-studio-code, git-bash

After Vs code update 1.60.0 terminal opens powershell but default remain same (git bash). If I create new terminal then it opens git bash.

when I start the app it looks likes:-

[image]

then I have to create new shell & it opens the default shell (git bash):-

[image]

Comment: It's a known problem in v1.60.0 that will hopefully be fixed soon.

Comment: tnx a lot @mklement0 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try first and set `terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows` to bash (if you want bash by default)

[image: bash]

That way, you don't have to switch from your current default Powershell terminal.

... Provided [`microsoft/vscode` issue 132149](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132149) is fixed, which is not the case, yet.
This is a duplicate of [issue 132150](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132150), which is now fixed by [commit c765e70](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/c765e70cf92bc4d2f08bdaa11ed1231063b7aa39), by [Megan Rogge](https://github.com/meganrogge).

```js
    async createTerminal(options?: ICreateTerminalOptions): Promise<ITerminalInstance> {
        if (!this._availableProfiles) {
            await this._refreshAvailableProfiles();
        }
```

---

Update Sept. 14th (2021): this is now fixed, with VSCode 1.60.1, and its [August 2021 Endgame Recovery](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/132426).

Comment: it was on . tnx...

Comment: @Sadhin This is already fixed in main: see my edited answer above. It should be available in 1.60.1 shortly.

Comment: @Sadhin VSCode 1.60.1 is now (Sept. 14th) out, and should fix the issue.

Comment: yes, it's fixed now. tnx...