# How to fix VS COde "fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error" on MacOS Monterey

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I'm getting "fatal error: runtime: bsdthread_register error" error on VS code when i try to run a command on terminal.

This used work fine on Big sur and older versions.

Is there a way to get this fixed on Monterey?

Comment: You might need to update VS Code to a Monterrey-compatible version

Comment: But they don't have such update. I tried different ide tools, getting the same error

Comment: You might have to wait until a new release comes out then

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

If this is a program you built from source, you will need to rebuild it with a newer version of Go:

https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/MacOS12BSDThreadRegisterIssue

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the issue of vscode. If you open your shell terminal, the error might still be there. Try changing your default terminal to zsh instead of bash. You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/vscode-change-default-terminal) to see how to change the vscode default terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The same situation happens when I use `goimports` command after upgrading go version to 1.17. Try to upgrade your go tools, Good Luck!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Since it's a MacBook:

```
brew install docker-machine
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while running command `ztoken`, I replaced it with `zign token uid cn` and now i dont get this error