# How to change VS Code Default Terminal to python

Tags: python-3.x, powershell, visual-studio-code

I am using Visual Studio Code on my Windows 10 PC. I want to change my default terminal from 'Windows PowerShell' to 'Python' (on Windows). Someone help me solve this issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VSCode Change Default Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/vscode-change-default-terminal)

Comment: No I want python as my default terminal this suggestion gives a common answer but not for python. If I can set python as my default terminal, please give that explanation in detail. Because I am a new learner of programming languages

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to bring up the command palette and run the `Terminal: Select Default Profile` command:

[image: Run command]

[image: Select Default Profile]

If Python does not appear here, [add a profile for it](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles) manually in your JSON configuration. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and run the `Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)` command:

[image]

Add the following lines in your JSON config file and save it:

```json
"terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "Python": {
        "path": "python",
        "args": []
    }
},
```

Afterwards you should be able to select `Python` as your default terminal profile.

Comment: Sorry, I tried this method but that didn't show the method I am asking.

Comment: Do you mean it does not display Python as an option? Do you have Python installed?

Comment: Yes it doesn't display python as an option but I have installed python.

Comment: Alright, I extended my answer with information on how to add a Python terminal profile.

Comment: Thank you for your answer it solved my problem :)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. I searched for "json", and while some of the other suggestions appeared, including "Preferences: Open Default Settings" & "Preferences: Open User Settings", the raw "Preferences: Open Settings" I did not see.
I tried copy-pasting to one, just in case, but it did not work. 
I then searched for "Preferences: Open Settings", and one of the results was "Preferences: Open Settings (UI)" - it's no longer a JSON file.
I do not think it would be a duplicate to ask this exact same question again.

Comment: @Post169: You are right, "Settings" seem to have been renamed to "User Settings" in a recent VS Code update. I updated the answer accordingly.