# Can I force Visual Studio 2022 > Git > Open In Command Prompt to use Git Bash instead of cmd?

Tags: git-bash, visual-studio-2022

Using Visual Studio 2022, I want to use the Git menu option Open In Command Prompt to open a Git Bash terminal as opposed to cmd.exe.

How do I configure VS to do this?

Comment: You may be able to do this by changing the [default terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/vscode-change-default-terminal) to Git Bash.

Comment: Hi @JeffMartin, that's for VS Code, rather than Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While not integrating to that menu, I was able to add git bash to the terminal window.

By choosing View > Terminal (or ctrl + ') and then selecting the settings cog and setting the following:

[image: Git Bash settings]

I am able to open a gitbash shell from within VS.

Note, that by setting the Shell location to C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe, the console loads a new instance of the console in its own window, by setting it to C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe, it is integrated in the Terminal Pane.

Answer (score 4):

Further to your own answer @StuperUser, you can set the Terminal up as follows:
[image: Git Bash Terminal]

This was taken from my Windows Terminal config when it added the Git Bash profile automatically. The arguments are `-i` for interactive and `-l` for login shell.

You could also try [Mads Kristensen's Open Command Line Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.OpenCommandLine) - it kind of works but has some quirks.