# Change the Python Terminal from Bash to CMD in VSCODE

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am trying to change the Executing Terminal for python in VSCode from Bash to CMD. I already tried changing the default terminal by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/vscode-change-default-terminal), but no luck.

**Detailed Explanation:**

In Vscode , when i hit the run button for executing python. I see that , the execution automatically chooses the Bash terminal , but i would need the execution to happen in CMD.

Answer (score 2):

You can check it in settings.

[image]

It's the same as adding the following line into your setting.json:

```
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Command Prompt",
```

If it still doesn't work, try reinstalling vscode

Answer (score 0):

If you just changed your default terminal, try restarting your computer, that worked for me, it wasn't taken into account before I did.