# error occured when install pyfmi in pip- is there any solution?

Tags: pyfmi

I'd like to install pyfmi but it kept failed.. I tried solutions on internet before, but nothing works..
would you give me solutions please??

(base) C:\Users\user>pip install pyfmi
Collecting pyfmi
Using cached PyFMI-2.5.tar.gz (4.8 MB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [6 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-l6733u74\pyfmi_8a142165ae444bbdb9d65b923602318f\setup.py", line 164, in 
raise Exception("FMI Library cannot be found. Please specify its location, either using the flag to the setup script '--fmil-home' or specify it using the environment variable FMIL_HOME.")
Exception: FMI Library cannot be found. Please specify its location, either using the flag to the setup script '--fmil-home' or specify it using the environment variable FMIL_HOME.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I tried PIP install

Comment: You say you've tried solutions... what exactly have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and all I can say is that I strongly advise you to not waste your time like I did trying to install every requirement by hand.

Use conda instead.

all you need to do is this:

First, Install anaconda :

- For linux: https://javedhassans.medium.com/install-miniconda-on-linux-from-the-command-line-in-5-steps-403912b3f378
- For windows (I did it on Git Bash):

https://www.anaconda.com/download

https://discuss.codecademy.com/t/setting-up-conda-in-git-bash/534473

Once that's installed on your prompt:

Creating the conda env:

- `conda create -n your_name_goes_here`
- `conda activate your_name_goes_here`
- `conda install python=3.6`
- `conda config --add channels conda-forge`
- `conda config --set channel_priority strict`
- `conda install pyfmi`

(thanks to conda forge https://github.com/conda-forge/pyfmi-feedstock)

if you're using visual studio code like me and want your packages to be recognized:

- Open your project folder in VS Code.
- Open the command palette with Ctrl+Shift+P
- Type and select "Python: Select Interpreter".
- VS Code will list available Python interpreters. Look for the one inside your Conda environment where PyFMI is installed. It will be something like:
- `~/anaconda3/envs/your_environment_name/bin/python.exe`
- Additionally, you might want to make git bash your default terminal [Change the default terminal in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44435697/change-the-default-terminal-in-visual-studio-code)

**Note**: you will have to reinstall some packages you are using in your code. If you want to install ***any*** other package just insert `conda install PACKAGE_NAME`, but I should mention that I Faced some issues with some libraries while installing such as matplotlib but fixes are always available if you search well! `https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/10949`

I hope this works for you !