# VSCode: 'py' command works but 'python' doesn't in the terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal, interpreter

When I'm trying to run my main.py file through VSCode terminal, it works fine if i use py main.py but shows the prompt of "how do you want to open this file?" when i use python command instead of py.

this issue is specific to vs code terminal. both py and python works fine on my windows terminal.

here's what i tried-

1. selected interpreter path
2. multiple reinstallations of python and vscode
3. checked system env path-> all set well
4. checked aliases
5. doskey python=py

what am i missing here?

Comment: If the PATH is set properly inside the VSCode terminal, then this has to work.  You've triple-checked that your python command is in the PATH?

Comment: You could be accidentally using Powershell (path starts with `PS C:\...`) instead of CMD.
https://stackoverflow.com/q/44435697/14536215

Comment: @Tzane  i selected CMD as my default terminal profile. this seems to be working fine

Comment: @TimRoberts yes i did set the path inside VSCode terminal and python command worked for only that terminal session. so tried to permanently set it in setting but wouldn't work

Comment: actually, everything was working fine until recently i installed google cloud sdk. could this problem possibly occur because of that?

Comment: Have you rebooted after setting the PATH in your environment variable control panel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I selected CMD as my default terminal profile, and it worked miraculously. Although I have been using Python for three years, I never faced such an issue before.

Answer (score 0):

In the command line try: python3 path/to/file/main.py
You can get the correct relative path to your file by right clicking on the file in VSCode and selecting 'Copy relative path'.

Comment: tried this already. didn't work