# Why is Visual Studio Code run not working?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

when I run python file in terminal I get this:

The terminal process:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" terminated with exit code: 4294901760.
```

Does anybody know why this is happening? If so could you please tell me how to fix it, I'm completely new to coding, and I've just been watching some tutorials on YouTube..

Comment: how are you rnning the p ython file?

Comment: if you are new I recommend an IDE (something that helps you write, troubleshoot, and run your code.  Intelij has a great one here(https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/#section=windows) community edition is free, or if you don't want to download anything and want to do it online go to www.replit.com and make an account. you get access to over 50 common languages and it's really easy to start playing around. You won't have to deal with windows abysmal integration of python3

Comment: This looks like a windows PowerShell issue (discussed here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114830) looks like they couldn't figure out what was wrong either :(

Comment: Sounds like three other people had this issue, only one managed to fix by downloading Powershell 7 and then reloading VS Code. They said: "picked up on that installation for me."

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You could try changing the default terminal to command prompt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425545/how-to-select-a-different-type-of-command-shell-in-the-visual-studio-code-integr