# How can I open Scilab in my Windows console?

Tags: scilab

How can I open Scilab in my Windows console? I have it installed and I see it when I search in the search bar but I don't know how to run it inside my console. I would like to use it inside my integrated Visual Studio Code terminal.

[image: Seaching the search bar]

Comment: What does this have to do with PowerShell? You can multiple consoles you choose in VSCode via settings and task customization as documented in the VSCode help files. [How do I ask a good question? - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ... 
[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example - Help Center - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ... 
[Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what Scilab is, never seen it, never used it. However as for the VScode terminal settings, this is a well-documented thing from Microsoft...

> [User and Workspace Settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings)
>
> [Integrated Terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

... and has been covered before on Stackoverflow.

[As per the accepted answer shows:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427631/how-to-add-multiple-terminals-in-vs-code)

> There is a way to make this happens with these steps by installing an
>   extension:
>
> Find an extension called Shell launcher and install it. Reload VS Code
>   if you want or after you finished all steps.
>
> Go to Files --> Preferences --> Settings and this will open
>   settings.json file and you then insert this (you can edit this to your
>   heart's content):
>
> Code:

```
"shellLauncher.shells.windows": [
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\<sysnative>\\cmd.exe",
        "label": "cmd"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\<sysnative>\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe",
        "label": "PowerShell"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin\\bash.exe",
        "label": "Git bash"
    },
    {
        "shell": "C:\\Windows\\<sysnative>\\bash.exe",
        "label": "WSL Bash"
    }
]
```

***Update***

I just took a look on Youtube for Scilab, and it has it's own completely stand-alone GUI console. You cannot run a GUI console in VScode, only terminal-like consoles, so, if it does have a cmd.exe -like, bash-like console, then the above approach applies.

Comment: It has something called "scilab-6.1.0 (64-bit) Console" which opens the console version of that program. I updated the `settings.json` by adding:
```json
{
            "shell": "C:\\Program Files\\scilab-6.1.0\\bin\\Scilex.exe",
            "label": "Scilab-cli"
        },
```
But after reopening VSC I still don't see it while trying to set new terminal

Comment: Nvm just got it to work. But after trying to execute a script that loads a few libraries it gives me an error that it cannot load some `.dll` libraries
`--> exec("./test.sce")

--> // load the blocks library and the simulation engine

--> loadXcosLibs(); loadScicos();
at line     2 of executed file E:\asdasasd\test.sce

Impossible to load scicos-cli.dll library`

Comment: In most cases like this, you may need to add the Scilab item to your system path and ps paths

Comment: I open the command line version of Scilab separately and it has the same error which I guess comes in pair with using the nonGUI version of that program as I tried to use `xcos` which is Scilabs version of Simulink (like in Matlab) and that is based on GUI

Comment: Good to know, you can repro this issue outside VSCode. So, my path statement above may be moot, as Scilab appears to have this catch22.

Comment: That exact library is located in `C:\Program Files\scilab-6.1.0\bin` so I added exactly that path to Enviroment Variable->PATH and it still shows that error:
`--> loadXcosLibs(); loadScicos();
at line     2 of executed file E:\asdasasd\test.sce

Impossible to load scicos-cli.dll library`

Comment: Looks like is simply doesn't want to display anything GUI related. I asked it so draw a simple plot and it refused. But your way of adding it to VSC terminal works. Thank you very much I'm sure I will use it in the future with something else! Thanks!