# Connect html-page with spreadsheet in vs code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, visual-studio-code

I try to repeat the actions from here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiPnkBEHqf0 and I have complication in time 0:50 where author opens Terminal in vsCode and works through bash.

I just have windows powershell instead bash (look the picture).

[image]

May be I need to set up vsCode before that or for windows I need do anything else? Thank you for helps!

I found one way to decide my problem here [How to add multiple terminals in VS Code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43427631/how-to-add-multiple-terminals-in-vs-code/50890703#50890703) I installed git bash by instruction but I have another problem (picture), when I write like in video 0:50

[image]

Comment: What is the complication exactly? Do you mean with node or apps script?

Comment: @iansedano  I mean apps-script. I found one way to resolve my problem, but now I have another problem, I put picture above

Comment: Sorry may be this is node. I need to coonect api of my apps-script project with vsCode like on video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### First install Node

Go to the website and install it:

> https://nodejs.org/en/

You shouldn't use Git Bash.

Once you have installed Node, which you can check by running this command from powershell:

```
node -v
```

If you get a version number, then you have installed successfully. You may need to reboot your computer after install.

#### Install Clasp

> https://github.com/google/clasp

By running this command:

```
npm install -g @google/clasp
```

Check the install by typing this command:

```
clasp
```

Which should give you some reference material.

#### Connect to your Apps Script Project

Once you have installed clasp, login by typing

```
clasp login
```

and then get your script ID and go to the folder you want to download your script to and:

```
clasp clone [SCRIPT ID]
```

More instructions are on the sites linked.

Comment: thank you very much!. I wil try near time) and write the result

Comment: I have one more question. Script ID is placed in google apps project in roperties? Or it is another script ID?

Comment: Look at the URL of the script, `https://script.google.com/home/projects/[SCRIPT ID]/edit`

Comment: And all these commands I need to start in node.js, right?

Comment: from powershell. you write the commands as i have written them above

Comment: Ok, and if I will publish the apps script project again then I must do this command again, ok? clasp clone [SCRIPT ID]

Comment: Once you have cloned it you can `clasp pull` to get updates and `clasp push` to send updates

Comment: thank you, I remember this. But I don't have enough time to test because of my job.