# Put console output in a Forms textbox (or something)? (C#)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, console

I'm working with an interesting coding environment that has unmanaged code, managed code, and C#. I have a GUI written in C#, and the associated console outputs stuff using unmanaged code that I don't really have access too. I was wondering if there is a way to read in the console to a text box in my GUI, or something like that? Basically just need access to the text in the console.

(One solution I tried was writing it to a text file, then reading it in, but its doesn't like that, because it is constantly writing)

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your unmanaged code is in a DLL or EXE?

Comment: did you have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-a-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application)?

Comment: Unmanged code is a DLL

Comment: @Mong Zhu, thank you for posting, but I did not have luck with that code

Comment: Without access to the code, how did you write it to a text file?

Comment: I have access to it, but I'm not supposed to be editing it, and its complex because its a massive project and way too much to convert from console to text

Comment: Maybe you could get away with redirecting stdout