# C# Override Console.Read() for a Windows Forms app

Tags: c#, overriding, console.readkey

i have following problem:

I am making a Windows Forms application and have to use other .cs Files which contain Console.Read() or Console.ReadLine(). The files should not be changed.
I would like now to override the functions in order to use a button or a Textbox + Button instead of the Console.Read().

Since i should not change the .cs files, this seems not to be too trivial.
Any ideas or leads?

Comment: Chck this, but not 100% sure if the method can work with static classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method

Comment: @Gusman Sadly it is not quite what i want, or maybe luckily? What i need is more something that would replace the Console.Read() with a "wait until Return was clicked" sniplet.

Comment: Well, that example shows how to replace a function of an existing class, so you can replace the Read() function with your own, but again, not sure if it will work for static classes like Console.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the `Console` as a stream using:

```
var stdIn = Console.OpenStandardInput();
```

Then when you click the button, you can call

```
stdIn.Write(Encoding.ASCII.ToBytes(txtMyBuffer.Text), 0, txtMyBuffer.Text.Length);
```

From reference: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.openstandardinput(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: First of all, thank you for your fast answere. The thing is, the Console.Read() is not overriden or redirected by snipplet. Somewhere in the .cs files a Console.Read() will pop up. Now i have to "satisfy" that Console.Read() with a Button click from a string (which can be from a textbox, but that is a lot more trivial!)

Comment: A console window is popping up?

Comment: No, the only thing is the Form itself

Comment: Then when you write the stdIn stream, it should be read in by your code in Console.Read(). It's the same stream.

Comment: But before i get to the button, i get an exception: ("Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file.")

Comment: Then I'm not sure, you may need to launch a console from your Forms app using PInvoke http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-a-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application