# Printing with the system echo cmd

Tags: c++, variables, c++-cli, echo

Ive got a form project in c++ and I need to be able to display a string in a console.
Here is my code (which doesnt work). Are there any better ways?

```
std::string neemac = GenMacAddr();
    //Copy
    String^ str2 = gcnew String(neemac.c_str());
    //Finish
    system("echo ------------------------------------ && echo Generated Mac: " + str2 + " && echo ------------------------------------ && pause");
```

Comment: Are you saying that your question is "How do I open a Console in a Windows Forms application"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I show a console output/window in a forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-a-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application)

Comment: Yeah that works, I just gotta figure out how to copy to clipboard then, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to display a string in the console you could use std::cout.
Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main()
{
  std::string myStr = "Hello";
  std::cout << myStr << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That wont work since im using framework and windows forms