# Is it possible to add Windows Forms to .NET Core console application?

Tags: winforms, .net-core, console, .net-4.8

Just like how we right click on the project and would be able to add Windows Form in the .NET Framework console application, is it possible to add Windows Form in .NET Core console application?

[image: .NET Framework console application]

[image: .NET Core console application]

Comment: Do it the other way round. Create a winforms application and open a console: [How do I show a console output/window in a forms application?How do I show a console output/window in a forms application?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4362111/880990).

Comment: It might be easier to add console app functionality to a winforms project.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes but I'm given the console application where I will have to work with. Even if I change the output type in the project properties back to the windows application I couldn't find the option to add windows form. Will I have to make any changes adding library or anything?

Comment: Create a .net 5 winforms app and you will see the dependencies it adds to the project. Also inspect the .csproj file to see the required settings (`<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>  <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>`). Also, the main routine must be `[STAThread]`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a .net core winform project, compile, manually reference `System.Windows.Forms.dll` and `System.Drawing.Common.dll` into the project, then use `[STAThread]` for the Main function, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

NuGet manager, Install-Package System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager