# Console application building as a windows application

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2019, console-application

For some reason my console application, using .NET 5, Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.2, builds and runs as a windows application.

In the csproj file it is set as `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` but in the "Application" page of the project properties GUI it shows as a "windows application" and changing it has no effect. When debugging or running it no console window is displayed.

How can I fix this?

Comment: The rest of the .csproj file matters as well.  When you have UseWPF or UseWindowsForms then you'll always get a WinExe, regardless of the OutputType.  Manually add `<DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>` to fix.

Comment: @HansPassant, oh, yeah I do have WPF and WinForms enabled, was using them for the Clipboard class. I'm fairly certain I could run a console app with them enabled before, though.

Comment: Its fine, just yet another annoying quirk about SDK-style projects.  We'll have to start calling them "bugs".

Comment: From your question，why not create a Windows Form project. Then: Project Properties -> Application -> Output Type -> Console Application  [How do I show a console output/window in a forms application?.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362111/how-do-i-show-a-console-output-window-in-a-forms-application) Does this help?