# Using "process" to call another program. Wanting to pass info back to parent program

Tags: vb.net

I know how to send parameters to the child program via `startinfo.arguments`. I think I even know how to "listen" to anything the child might "say" via `standardoutput.readline`. What I don't know is what method to use for the child to "speak" back to the parent. Here is the code I have so far (on the parent side):

```
Dim proc As Process
Dim bRunProgramWorked As Boolean = True
Try
    proc = New Process
    Dim procInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
    proc.StartInfo.FileName = strPathUpgradeEXE
    proc.StartInfo.Arguments = param1 & " " & param2 & " " & param3
    proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    'proc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
    proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
    proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
    proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    'proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
    proc.Start()
    Dim output1 As String = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine
    Dim output2 As String = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine
    proc.WaitForExit()
    proc.Close()
    proc.Dispose()
Catch ex As Exception
    LogIt(strMyBaseID, "Error at trying to run PVT-Export. " & ex.ToString)
    bRunProgramWorked = False
End Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child process needs to write to `Console.Out`.

Comment: Do you mean using "console.writeline"?

Comment: Does the problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2638030/console-write-not-working-in-win-forms-app apply? In other words, is there something special I need to do if my child app is a windows form type application and not a console application?

Comment: @ScotterMonkey `WriteLine()` will also work (it writes to `Console.Out`)

Comment: That question is only relevant if you want to run the inner process from a console and have it take over the console.  It has nothing to do with the standard streams themselves.